# Dynamics 365 - Chatbot - Link Visitor Name to Active Conversation page from Pre-Conversation Survey

Tags: chat, chatbot, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, power-virtual-agents

**Problem:** I have a chatbot that uses a pre-conversation survey to grab a visitor's name and email. When the chatbot escalates the conversation to an agent I want it link the Name of the visitor to active conversation page and communication panel automatically. Currently the chatbot defaults to Visitor 1 / 2 etc. when escalating chats not in our contact center.

**Technical Note:** Chatbot is able to identify customers that already exists in our contacts and links them automatically upon escalation using the pre-conversation chat. The problem is when users who are not in our contacts is escalated it does not include the name input from users during the pre-conversation survey prompt.

Reference screenshots below.

Case 1: Existing Customer Found - Active Conversation Page - Bot Escalates With Name

**Escalated Chat Notification - Existing Customer**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huegu.jpg)

**Escalated Chat - Existing Customer - Active Conversation Page**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZSEE.jpg)

Case 2: Visitor - Active Conversation Page - Bot Escalates with no name

**Escalated Chat Notification - Visitor  - Existing Customer**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxyco.jpg)

**Escalated Chat - Visitor - Active Conversation Page**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STYnF.jpg)

1.) Setup Pre-conversation survey to grab name and email of user
2.) Ensured the bot escalating the issue is using the Name and Email as context variabler
3.) Ensured the workstream bot is escalating to has logical name of context variables. name for Name and emailaddress1 for Email
4.) Tested and verified the chat bot is able to identify existing customer information.